# Limud HaRambam by all Yidden

Tags: torah-study, rambam, chabad

Do non-Lubavitchers learn Rambam (any of the cycles divided by the Rebbe)?
I know that when the Rebbe launched the campaign he intended that all Yidden join.
How did that come about?

Comment: I don't whether anyone else took their schedule, but in Brisk Rambam is a key point of learning.

Comment: I don't think so. I never heard of it until an Ex-Lubavitcher mentioned it to me.

Comment: In Israel quite a few Dati people take part in the Rambam Yomi study cycle.

Comment: As I recall, when this was started, the Rebbe pointed out that this was something that the previous generation in Europe (not specifically Chabad) had attempted to institute unsuccessfully. It might have been something tried by Agudas Yisroel. Not Sure about that.

Comment: Baltimore and Brooklyn: I have never heard about it outside of Chabad.